# Avoid multiple connections to a shared folder from one specific user on one specific client

Tags: windows, connection, shared-folders, session, windows-networking

Connection to a shared folder on client **client-A** (Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC) keeps getting blocked with the error message

> No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time
> because there are already as many connections as the computer can
> accept.

The connection to this shared folder is limited to 10 sessions which is fine. Multiple users from different clients regularly access the shared folder. The sessions do open and close as expected. However, one specific user **currentuser** from one specific client **client-B** (Windows Server 2012 R2) keeps accumulating open sessions which do not close (see image). These sessions can get easily [closed manually](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/how-to-disconnect-user-or-users-from-a-shared-folder-or-dri/) in `Computer Management` > `Shared Folders` > `Sessions`. However, this is not a sustainable solution. Increasing the maximum number of sessions by either [properties of the folder](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d76bcc3f-0a2a-402c-8ac8-647b2d00e32e/winpe-quotno-more-connections-can-be-made-to-this-remote-computer-at-this-time-because-there-are?forum=w7itproinstall) or [registry](https://steemit.com/tutorial/@afterglow/tutorial-no-more-connections-can-be-made-to-this-remote-computer-at-this-time-because-there-are-already-as-many-connections-as) is not a solution as well - if it was possible at all - as it does not address the cause of this problem.

How does it come that there are multiple sessions open for **currentuser** on **client-B**? Is there any property, which could get changed in order get only one connection open for **currentuser** on **client-B**? All properties reviewed so far are globally for all users and do not look like to be the cause, e.g. `idle session time`. I think the [licensing method](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/273244-users-opening-multiple-sessions-under-shared-folder) 'per server' / 'per user' is not a reason as the problem only occurs for one specific user on one specific client.

Both clients work with Windows 10 Pro.

[image]

Comment: Do all sessions come from the same IP address? Are there any firewalls or even NAT gateways between you and client-B (excluding Windows' built-in firewall)? I'm suspecting either client-B assumes the connection has already been closed by the server or its attempts to close it never reach the server (due to lost firewall state).

Comment: All sessions come from the same domain (e.g. 111.222.333.xyz), the IP address differ in the last 3 digits only (i.e. xyz does vary). Significant could be, that client-B is a virtual machine which is located physically at another location. However, it is within the same company's network and, thus, should be behind the same firewall. Anyhow: how could the firewall state get checked in connection with this problem?

Comment: So the address *does* differ. Why does it change? Does the VM get restarted? Does the address belong to the VM directly, or is it assigned through NAT?

Comment: All 3 sessions all indicate the idle time is minutes, which is strange, considering they are all the exact same value.

Comment: It looks like we run into a misunderstanding: with “change of IP-address” I mean “change due to access from another client” only. It’s the same IP-address as long as it’s the same client. The FQDN of client-B always points to the same IP-address.

Comment: I have this problem too. When I go to "Open Files" the server shows files open for "client-B", when those files were closed over a day ago.  I also sometimes get the error "Can't flush file to disk: Insufficient system resources exist."  I fix this by force closing the sessions. Sometimes I must reboot the machines, because even closing the session still shows the file open with the "accessed by" column showing "[Disconnected]"  Using handle.exe on the client confirms that the session and files were indeed closed.